# How to comment out/in a paragraph of haml in vi?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I just started diving into vi and so far learned only basic moving around/editing commands. While I am going through the book, is there a fast way to comment out a paragraph with `-#` in the same column with the cursor position (indenting the lines accordingly)?

Let's say I have a piece of code:

```
%table
  - unless paginate(@clients).nil?
    %tr
      %th
        =t('index.name')
      %th
        =t('index.address')
      %th
        =t('index.phone')
    =render :partial => 'client', :collection => @clients
```

and I want to comment out lines between `- unless` and `=render :partial` with `-#` in one column and then be able to comment them in again. What command would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blockwise select mode, you can press `I` to insert in front of the block and `A` to insert after the block.

Setting `'relativenumber'` (`:set rnu`) could help to count lines.

Start with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> to switch to blockwise select mode, then `8j` to go down eight lines, then `I#`<kbd>Esc</kbd> to insert the `#`.

To remove it: `d`<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>8j will delete blockwise.

Warning, if you happen to use vanilla gvim.exe on Windows, you probably have `mswin.vim` activated which remaps CTRL-V, use then CTRL-Q instead (or disable this plugin)

Comment: Hm... using `I` (when I am in the blockwise select mode) throws me out of that block mode and I only manage to insert symbols at the current cursor position (naturally, I am already in the insert mode).

Comment: You must hit `<Esc>` for your changes to be applied to all the lines.

Comment: Of course it worked. Reference for this: `:help blockwise-visual` and `:help blockwise-operators`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're less interested about the how and just want it to work, there are a number of plugins that provide (un)commenting functionality for varieties of languages.  Tim Pope's commentary.vim is the one I just started using recently, as a replacement for [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter).

I just installed it so I can't speak to any defects, but Tim Pope's stuff is (nearly?) always excellent.  With the plugin you could comment a Haml paragraph by selecting a visual block and typing `\\\`.  It also takes motions, e.g. `\\ap`.

The link:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Answer (score 0):

If you use it often, you can define a command in your `.vimrc`

```
command -range=% C :<line1>,<line2>s/^/-#/
```

Then in vi, you can apply `:<range>C` in the usual manner. You can do this with `:10,20C` or `.,+10C`. You can use the following command for uncommenting.

```
command -range=% D :<line1>,<line2>s/^-#//
```

Since I am using vi for with languages with different types of commenting, I also us these commands:

```
command -range=% -nargs=1 Ca :<line1>,<line2>s/^/<args>/
command -range=% -nargs=1 Da :<line1>,<line2>s/^<args>//
```

Allowing you to just do `:10,20Ca-#`, where you can replace `-#` with the commenting method of choice.

Comment: Thanks, I found it useful (have to get used to it though).