# vim nerd commenter range command

Tags: vim

I found [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375031/nerd-commenter-how-to-comment-out-a-range), but I want to do something different. When using nerd command, in normal mode You can do:

```
5ggv12gg,c<space>
```

It will toggle comment from line 5 to 12. But instead I would like to be able to write:

```
:5,12Ct
```

So I tried to write my own command for that using predefined nerd commenter command:

```
command! -nargs=? -range=% Ct <line1>ggv<line2>gg<Leader>c<space>
```

but as I assumed it gives me an error "not an editor command: 5ggv12gg,c " - probably because it expects command like :something, not normal mode command.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Side note, I never use `gg` but `G` to go to a specific line (except the first one). I would like a poll to know what habits stackers have regarding that…

Comment: @Benoit, I use `:12` to jump to specific line.

Comment: @Lucas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175314/how-to-comment-out-in-a-paragraph-of-haml-in-vi/9226398#9226398 This may help you a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:normal`, as in `:normal <line1>ggv<line2>gg<Leader>c<space>`.  See `:help normal` for details.