# how to load vim command based on plugin command in vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I tried to make vim command using [Nerd Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin. Basically after some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378434/vim-nerd-commenter-range-command), it looks like:

```
command! -nargs=? -range=% Ct :normal <line1>ggv<line2>gg<Leader>c<space>
```

It works when I use `:so .vimrc`, but when I restart vim it only performs <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> without <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>. I guess it is because the <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> part is from plugin, but I wonder if there is some way to fix this. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are defining the command before setting "mapleader" in your .vimrc?

From `:help mapleader`:

```
Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
mappings.
```